# What does this message from kernel mean?

Tags: virtualbox

When I start VirtualBox, I got warning: `VirtualBox' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)`

It seems harmless though, but I still would like to know what that means? And why did I get that?

I run a 64bit `Arch Linux` with Intel VT (i5 CPU), `VT enabled`.

While checking 32bit files in /usr/lib/virtualbox, I got:

```
%> find . -type f -exec is32elf {} \;
./VBoxDD2GC.gc
./VMMGC.gc
./VBoxDDGC.gc
./ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.amd64/VBoxEhciRC.rc
./ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.x86/VBoxPuelMain.so
./ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.x86/VBoxEhciR0.r0
./ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.x86/VBoxPciRawR0.r0
./ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.x86/VBoxVRDP.so
./ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.x86/VBoxEhciRC.rc
./ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.x86/VBoxEhciR3.so
./ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.x86/VBoxPciRawDrv.so
./ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.x86/VBoxUsbCardReaderR3.so
./ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.x86/VBoxPciRawR3.so
./ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/solaris.x86/VBoxPuelMain.so
./ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/solaris.x86/VBoxEhciR0.r0
./ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/solaris.x86/VBoxVRDP.so
./ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/solaris.x86/VBoxEhciRC.rc
./ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/solaris.x86/VBoxEhciR3.so
./ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/solaris.x86/VBoxUsbCardReaderR3.so
./ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/solaris.amd64/VBoxEhciRC.rc
```

Maybe that can explain something?

Comment: might seem like a dumb question but: VT is enabled in your BIOS right?  also what OS are you running?

Comment: @h3rrmiller added to question, arch linux, VT enabled

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has to do with a kernel header version mismatch.  You're right, it is completely harmless though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It just means that virtualbox uses the old *Linux capability* API. It's deprecated but still supported, and the warning is there to tell virtualbox developers to move on and use the new one.